# TortoiseGIT checkout goes on for ever.. any turn around?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am trying to do a pull , initally had problems where it would say "git did not abort cleanly " and pull half the files. After multiple reverts I thought I managed to get a pull working but now this process goes on and on , doesn't end. (the globe keeps throwing the tortoise to the folder :P)

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found out the upgrading tortoise git , fixed the issue. Eventually I got rid of Tortoise git and moved to using GIT bash.